# How can I ping devices on Class B network when remote VPN issues Class A network address?

Tags: networking, sophos

I've been playing with the Sophos UTM Home Edition, and I've noted that SSL VPN connections are issued Class A addresses. Given that the current internal network leases Class B addresses, why can I ping `172.20.1.100` from `10.242.1.1` and vice versa? Is the UTM managing routing between the two networks internally?

Comment: By "Class A" do you mean an address with a 255.0.0.0 subnet or are you referring to the old classes that haven't been used since the mid-90s?

Comment: Not even aware of those. I was referring to your standard /8 range.

Comment: Having just reread your question, an address on a 10/8 network will still be able to ping a 172.16/12 address.

Comment: Also, the 10.242.2.0 pool used by SSL VPN is a /24 by default, so there's no need to worry.

Comment: I was more curious as to why these two networks can "see" each other. Are they not completely different networks, and should therefore need a router to pass traffic between them?

Comment: As Daniel has stated, your UTM is a router in and of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the UTM does, as every other router, route the packet from one network into the other. But you had to allow that pings will be forwarded by the firewall somewhere.

Comment: No so much concerned about pings as I was packets. I wanted to know how traffic passes seemlessly across the different networks. I'm guessing that the UTM automatically routes traffic internally.

Comment: I just told you that the UTM routes the traffic. Read the answer again.